# std::function parameter is incomplete type not allowed

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to assign a lambda to an `std::function`, like so:

```
std::function<void>(thrust::device_vector<float>&) f;
f = [](thrust::device_vector<float> & veh)->void
{   
    thrust::transform( veh.begin(), veh.end(), veh.begin(), tanh_f() );
};
```

And I get an error:

```
 error: incomplete type is not allowed
 error: type name is not allowed
```

I think it refers to `thrust::device_vector<float>`. I tried typenaming and typedefining the parameter:

```
typedef typename thrust::device_vector<float> vector;
std::function<void>(vector&) f;
f = [](vector & veh)->void
{   
    thrust::transform( veh.begin(), veh.end(), veh.begin(), tanh_f() );
};
```

To no avail. However, if I just use the lambda (without the `std::function`) it works:

```
typedef typename thrust::device_vector<float> vector;
auto f = [](vector & veh)->void
{   
    thrust::transform( veh.begin(), veh.end(), veh.begin(), tanh_f() );
};
```

What am I missing?
PS: I am compiling using `nvcc release 6.5, V6.5.12` and `g++ (Debian 4.8.4-1) 4.8.4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax.

Try `std::function<void(thrust::device_vector<float>&)> f;` instead

`std::function<void(thrust::device_vector<float>&)> f;` declares a variable with type `std::function<void(thrust::device_vector<float>&)>`, which is a function object that takes `thrust::device_vector<float>&` and return `void`

g++ give you the incomplete type error because `std::function<void>` is not a valid template instantiation.

clang++ give you a better error message telling you that `std::function<void>() f;` is an invalid variable declaration:

```
main.cpp:11:28: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    std::function<void>(int) f;
                        ~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: @Alex it is alright. you made a common mistake and I think this question and answer will benefit other people who made similar mistake.

Comment: Is that actually legal syntax? Does `int(int) fp;` declare a pointer to a function that takes an int and returns an int?

Comment: @immibis no; although `int(int)` is a type (a function type, not a pointer type!), declarations of variables must use *infix notation*: (aka. "declaration follows usage").  We call the function as `fp(5);` so the declaration must be `int (*fp)(int)`, where the `*` is necessary to make it a pointer type, and the parentheses necessary to prevent the `*` being associated with the return value.

Comment: similar to how we can't write `int[5] arr;`

Comment: @M.M That's what I thought; a previous revision of this answer claimed that `std::function<void>(thrust::device_vector<float&>) f;` was a valid declaration of a function pointer.